# Mastering API for mp3 files

Tags: mp3

Can any one help me which API use by (http://www.landr.com)  for mastering the files.
and suggest me other option as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a developer at LANDR. We are using our own core technology. The API is not yet pubic or commercially available, though we are considering it.

Contact me directly if you have any questions or want to know more.

Comment: can I speak to you about the LANDR API?

Comment: sure, you can find me on twitter @mchambaud